# Object Array in Java does not take arguments

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I am writing a program in Java and I made two classes. In the second one I made an array but i can't place any arguments inside.

`

```
public class Teams {
    String Name;
    private String Country;
    private int Score;
public Teams(String Name, String Country, int Score) {
this.Name = Name;
this.Country = Country;
this.Score = Score;
}
public String getCountry() {   
    return Country;
}
public int getScore() {
    return Score;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Team Name: " + Name + " Team Country: " + Country + " Team Score: " + Score + ".";          }
}
```

`

that was my first class now this is the second

`

```
public class TD {
    
public void enterTeam(int N){

    Teams[] team = new Teams(String Name, String Country, int Score);
       Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            
        System.out.println("Enter a name for your team: ");
        Name = t.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the country of origin: ");
            Country = t.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n Enter a score for the team: ");  
        Score = t.nextInt();
        TeamNumber++;
    }
}
```

`

i was trying to place some arguments in the array but it didn't accept them and my ide kept giving me this error

`constructor Teams() cannot be applied to given types required: String, String, int found: no arguments`

Comment: Off-topic: Java naming conventions have variable names beginning with a lower-case letter: `name`, `country`, `score`, `n`.

Comment: You probably want `Teams[] team = new Teams[N]`. In your loop, after the user enters the specifics, have `team[i] = new Teams (Name, Country, Score);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
Teams[] team = new Teams(String Name, String Country, int Score);
```

you declare an array but init a `Teams` object. change your initial of a new object to an initial of an array and create a new `Teams` object inside the loop for your array